# JSON structured data description shows html tags

Tags: json, wordpress, strip, structured-data

On our site we use JSON to display our structured data. One of the fields (reviewBody) returns the text within p tags. I would like to remove the opening and closing tags.

Who can help me out stripping the tags?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Review",
    "image": "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>",
    "reviewBody": <?=json_encode(apply_filters('the_content', $tw_entry->review_summary)); ?>,
    "description": "<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true); ?>",
    "datePublished": "<?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>",
    "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "<?php the_title(); ?>"
    },
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "mr x"
    },
    "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "10",
        "ratingValue": "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'average-rating', true)/10; ?>",
        "worstRating": "1"
    } 
}
</script>
```

results in:

```
"reviewBody": <p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: you mean no html tags ? only content?

Comment: yes, I need the '<p>' and '</p>' to go. So i will only remain with the "lorem ipsum"

Comment: change this `<?=json_encode(apply_filters('the_content', $tw_entry->review_summary)); ?>` to this `<?php echo json_encode(wp_filter_nohtml_kses($tw_entry->review_summary)); ?>`

Comment: Thanks mister Noman, that's it! Saviour of the day!

Comment: can you accept answer? if yes then i would add as answer

Comment: please do add as answer

Comment: i've added the answer

Answer (score 0):

To strip html, you need to use [**wp_filter_nohtml_kses**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses) 
So, change this

```
<?=json_encode(apply_filters('the_content', $tw_entry->review_summary)); ?>
```

to this

```
<?php echo json_encode(wp_filter_nohtml_kses($tw_entry->review_summary)‌​); ?>
```